# Probability of event E and F

Tags: probability

Let E and F be two independent events . The probability that exactly one of them occurs is 11/25 and the probability of none of them ocuurring is 2/25 . We have to find P(E) & P(F) .

I always get confused in these type of problems .

In this I only know $P(E\cup F) = P(A)+P(B)-P(E\cap F)$

Comment: I know how to help you with an easy way but I don't know how to write it down in the answer...if you could help me with Letex you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might mean to say:
$$\mathbb P(E\cup F) = \mathbb P(E)+\mathbb P(F)-\mathbb P(E\cap F)$$

And by definition of independent events, we know
$$\mathbb P(E\cap F) = \mathbb P(E)\cdot \mathbb P(F)$$

**Long way to solve it**

Exactly one event: 
$$\mathbb P((E \cap F ^c) \cup (F \cap E^c)))$$

Neither of them happens:
$1-\mathbb P(E\cup F)$

**Short way to solve it**

Alternatively, a better way to go is use the probability of exactly one event and neither event, and get the probability of both $E$ and $F$ happens, and thus you get $$\mathbb P(E \cap F)=\mathbb P(E)\cdot\mathbb P(F)=1-\frac{2}{25} -\frac{11}{25}=\frac{12}{25}$$

Combined with $$1-\mathbb P(E\cup F)=1 -\mathbb P(E)-\mathbb P(F)+\mathbb P(E\cap F)=\frac{2}{25}$$

Comment: What is the use of 11/25

Comment: @Koolman Hey, I've added a hint for that case of 11/25. Plus, not sure you are blocked on this, but if$ E,F $independent, you could find that $\mathbb P(E \cap F^c) = \mathbb P(E)\cdot \mathbb P(F^c)$

Comment: @Koolman Just made another update. So a better alternative is to figure out the probability that both $E,F$ happen.